# CSS : create 2 groups of two input text

Tags: html, css

I would like to reproduce this interface :

[image]

There is 2 groups of 2 glued input text elements.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

**http://jsfiddle.net/9u6Jj/**

HTML:

```
<div class="input_fields">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.input_fields { width: 200px; }

input[type="text"] { margin-bottom: 15px; }
```